# SQL grouping in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Re all,

I need a little help with SQL. I got two SQL queries:

the first one counts how many occurences of a certain condition:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM table1
WHERE condition1 = @condition
```

the second one select each row that match the same condition on the same table joined with a secondary table:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2
ON table2.id = table1.id_sub
WHERE condition1 = @condition
```

Using both these queries in interactive fashion (by code) I can achieve the result I need but I want to optimize the procedure using SQL features instead coding.

What I really need is a query that reports just a single row for each group of rows that matches condition1. 
I need also to insert the count of the matching rows as a field of the result row.

I'm running MySQL 5.6 and code the application trough Visual Studio 2013 Pro coding in C# (using MySQL.Data package).

Best Regards,
 WeirdGyn

Comment: Of course I need only the SQL code.

Comment: I've written a possible answer but without further clarification on your table structures and what columns you need to return it's hard to say if these answer will be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is `GROUP BY` the `condition1` field.  It would also appear that if you just need the `COUNT` by group that you wouldn't need the join.

```
SELECT condition1, COUNT(*)
FROM table1
--INNER JOIN table2
--    ON table1.id_sub = table2.id
GROUP BY condition1
```

Comment: Sorry but I forgot to mention that condition1 (in the second query) is based on data from table2 (that's why I need INNER JOIN).